# How do I secure the shower valve without removing tile?

Tags: bathroom, remodeling

The plumber didn't secure the new valve to the frame, so the shower valve and head were left loose and it is wiggling. The new tile is completed and we do not want to redo it.

What is the best way to secure the valve and shower head?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to be creative, but the best solution is to open the wall on the opposite side behind the valve.  Hopefully you have drywall or a closet and not an outside wall.  Drywall repair is cheaper and easier than tile repair.  In many areas it is code to have an access hatch to reach the bathtub trap, so you may be able to reach it from there.

Other option is to bust out as few tiles as possible.  You should have a few spares from the tile work, or if it is recent you may be able to buy a few to patch the damage.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to mfaver answer. You could also take the flanges off the taps and shower rose and try and pump silicon or another non-porous substance into the annular space, once it sets it will hold the shower valve in place against the wall and tile backing. Not the most professional solution but it avoids opening the wall up.

Comment: Not a bad idea:  Spray foam (Great Stuff) might also be a good choice.  It will make a mess if ever the valve needs replacing, but it sets up firm and is an excellent adhesive.  Cover the critical front areas of the valve and threads with tape or another suitable masking.  It would be a horrible hack, but it would probably work.

Comment: but would suck up water unless you get a water proof variety

Answer (score 0):

If the valve is sitting on framing then you could peek into the cavity to see where the mounting points contact the framing.  Drill holes through the tile slightly larger than screw heads and screw the valve down through the wall.  The escutcheons should cover the newly drilled holes, and if not you may be able to get larger remodel type trim that will.

Or, tell the plumber to fix his mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I have pulled out several valves without retyling... Most were through the back of the wall.  A couple I did from the front doing the following...

An adjustable fan brace, wire wrap, and silicone.  Get an adjustable fan brace and install it right over or behind the valve.  Once it is fully secure wrap the valve (ALOT) in many directions.  There is also creative uses of mounts and brackets attached to the brace.  And finish off with silicone to the brace.